# FolderBrowsingDialog doesn't open the next FolderBrowsingDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

FolderBrowsingDialog doesnt load the next one. i tried f1 and f2 alone, and it shows me the desktop folder. But when i tried f1&f2 together. only f1 loads

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FolderBrowserDialog f1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FolderBrowserDialog f2 = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        f1.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        f2.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        f1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
        f2.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;

        //f1.Description = "Source";
        //f2.Description = "Destination";

        string folderPathCopy = string.Empty;
        string folderPathPaste = string.Empty;

        if (f1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            folderPathCopy = f1.SelectedPath;
        }

        if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)//Debugging stops here
        {
            folderPathPaste = f2.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
```

the problem is, f2 doesnt run.

Comment: Did you *close* the first dialog?

Comment: i chose a folder in desktop and press ok, then f2 doesnt open.

Comment: Opening dialog boxes in the *constructor* of a form is very unusual. The form *doesn't* exist yet, which means it can't be used as a parent for other forms, controls. Use the Load event. This won't change the behaviour of `ShowDialog()` though. It won't return until you close the dialog

Comment: If you look at my answer, I'm guessing there is something wrong with trying to show these dialogs in the constructor of your form, I decided to try moving the code until after the initial form is shown.

Comment: FYI - I tried the "Load" event, and it didn't work, but the "Shown" event did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code into the "Shown" event:

```
     public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Shown += Form1_Shown;

      }

      private void Form1_Shown( object sender, EventArgs e )
      {
         FolderBrowserDialog f1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
         FolderBrowserDialog f2 = new FolderBrowserDialog();

         f1.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
         f2.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

         f1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
         f2.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;

         //f1.Description = "Source";
         //f2.Description = "Destination";

         string folderPathCopy = string.Empty;
         string folderPathPaste = string.Empty;

         if ( f1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
         {
            folderPathCopy = f1.SelectedPath;
         }

         if ( f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )//Debugging stops here
         {
            folderPathPaste = f2.SelectedPath;
         }
      }
```

Comment: And why would that make any difference?

Comment: Try it out, it does.  My guess is that it isn't normal to be bringing up UI during the constructor of a form.

Comment: @DavidG it might - there is no *parent* form when `ShowDialog` is called in the constructor.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I meant more like "explain why this helps rather than a code dump", probably should have taken more time to say that :)

Comment: it works. but the problem is, the form is showing in different location, dialog also in different direction. when i add this.Hide() in start of method, it doesnt load both dialog because dialogs are inside forms. how can i fix this?

Comment: You don't want the main form to show?  You could add this.Opacity = 0; in the form constructor.